# Is there a list of playable races with a fly speed?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, races, flight

Essentially I'm looking for a list of playable races and creatures that have flight to begin with.  I know of a few with no LA, but I'm also looking for anything from LA +1 to +3 I'd say.  More emphasis on the lower end though.  I know there are several ways to get flight, but I'm looking for creatures that have it to begin with.  The Winged template doesn't count, though it is something I'm keeping in mind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Combining information from the [Master +0 LA Race List](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=1281.0) (minmaxboards), [Player Race List with LA +1 and LA +2](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=342.0) (minmaxboards) and [LA +1 & LA +2 Player Race List](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?189980-3-5-LA-1-amp-LA-2-Player-Race-List) (GitP), we can find lots of applicable races.

This gives us:

**LA +0**

- Anthropomorphic Bat (20' average), Savage Species
- Anthropomorphic Raven (20' poor), Savage Species
- Crane Hengeyokai (20' average), Oriental Adventures, updated in Dragon 318
- Sparrow Hengeyokai (20' average), Oriental Adventures, updated in Dragon 318
- Raptoran (40' average after 6HD), Races of the Wild 66

Also listed the the Dragonborn with wings (30' average, Races of the Dragon), and the Unseelie Fey template, which has functional wings half the time (2x land speed average, Dragon Compendium).

**LA +1**

- Air Mephling (10' perfect), Planar Handbook
- Anthropomorphic Owl (20' poor), Savage Species

**LA +2**

- Anthropomorphic Hawk (30' poor), Savage Species
- Aarakocra (90' average), Monsters of Faerûn
- Fey'ri (40' poor), Races of Faerûn
- Gloaming (40' average), Underdark
- Petal (60' good), Monster Manual III

Also listed is the "Phaeton" from what looks like a Dragonlance book called Key of Destiny. 60' average.

Note: Most of these are extracted from the lists. I have not confirmed them all myself.

Answer (score 8):

## Some Playable Flying, Almost Flying, and Occasionally Flying Creatures

I used sources similar to [Ernir's](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/39605/8610), but [KRyan's](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/39606/8610) got the right idea. In all cases, add racial hit dice to Level Adjustment to class levels to determine effective character level.

### LA +0

- **Anthropomorphic Bat (*SS* 216):** Fly 20 ft. (average).
- **Anthropomorphic Raven (*SS* 216):** Fly 30 ft. (poor).
- **Hadozee (*Sto* 41-3):** Never technically fly but glide instead at 40 ft. (average).
- **Raptoran (*RW* 65-90):** Don't technically fly-*fly* until reaching 10 HD when they have a fly speed of 40 ft. (average); they glide at 40 ft. (average) until 5 HD, and from 5 HD until 9 HD they glide and fly at 40 ft. (average) to remain aloft.
- **Phanaton (*Dragon* #351 71):** Never technically fly but glide instead at 20 ft. (average).
- **Shifter (*RoE* 25-40):** A shifter with the swiftwing trait when shifted gains fly 20 ft. (average).

### LA +1

- **Air Mephling (*PlH* 10-11):** Fly 10 ft. (perfect).
- **Anthropomorphic Eagle (*SS* 216):** 2 monstrous humanoid racial HD. Fly 40 ft. (poor).
- **Anthropomorphic Owl (*SS* 216):** 1 monstrous humanoid racial HD. Fly 20 ft. (poor).

### LA +2

- **Aarakocra (*Rac* 130-2):** Fly 90 ft (average).
- **Anthropomorphic Hawk (*SS* 216):** 1 monstrous humanoid racial HD. Fly 30 ft. (poor).
- **Fey'ri<sup>1</sup> (*Rac* 118-21):** Fly 40 ft (poor).
- **Gloaming (*Und* 12-13):** Fly 40 ft. (average).
- **Nycter (MM3 112-3):** 3 monstrous humanoid racial HD. Fly 40 ft. (good).
- **Petal<sup>2</sup> (MM3 120):** Fly 60 ft. (good).
- **Windrazor (*MM4* 179):** 2 outsider racial HD. Fly 40 ft. (good).

---

1. Fey'ri LA can be higher depending on options picked.
2. Petals, officially, are ineligible for PCs; a LA is given for their status as cohorts.

Answer (score 4):

The only LA +0 races that natively get a flight speed without investment are the raptorans (*Races of the Wild*) and the dragonborn (*Races of the Dragon*). Both of these start out with a glide ability that becomes true flight (at 5 HD and 6 HD, respectively). Flight is but one option for dragonborns, but it’s the best one.

Dragonblood races (silverbrow humans, deepwyrm half-drow, fireblood dwarves, forestlord elves and half-elves, stonehunter gnomes, glimmerskin halflings, viletooth lizardfolk, and sunscorch hobgoblins from *Dragon Magic*, dragonborn, dragonwrought kobolds, and spellscales from *Races of the Dragon*, as well as anyone who takes the Dragontouched feat from *Dragon Magic*) can take Dragon Wings as a 1st-level feat and Improved Dragon Wings as a 6th-level feat to get flight (*Races of the Dragon*).

Any evil character can get the feathered wings graft from *Fiend Folio* for a quite-good flight speed at a rather affordable 10,000 gp. Anyone who is not evil risks going mad if they get the graft.

Races with LAs larger than LA +0 that happen to have flight are numerous; too many for a proper SE answer. I know of no list that *specifically* lists only these races, but the [LA +1 and +2 race list](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?189980-3-5-LA-1-amp-LA-2-Player-Race-List) will help you find the more reasonably-playable choices, to find out which have flight.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a Character race, the only one I remember is the Raptoran, from Race of the Wild. The PC can't fly at the beginning but obtain this ability once lv5 (if I remember well).

If you don't need to fly at each instant, a lycanthrope like a Wereowl Halfling should be ok : if it's not a natural lycanthrope, the LA should be +2 (against +4 for a natural one)

Comment: Raptoran is the only race I remember too.  Some creatures I remember are Anthro Bats/Ravens, and there's Dragonborn that choose the Wings feature, but besides that I know there are at least a handful of low LA playable creatures that get wings but they're hard to find.